# pandas datetime to index bug OR possible time travel discovery

Tags: python, pandas

Is this a bug? It looks like pushing a datetime object into a dataframe, then indexing on the datetime column, does some scrambling of the date but produces no error (see line 97). Interestingly the view looks right so I'm *guessing* it's some sort of memory indexing thing.

This was on a fairly recent build of pandas: pandas-0.9.1.dev_85d982d-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg.

```
In [93]: import datetime, pandas
In [94]: df = pandas.DataFrame([[datetime.datetime.today(), 12.1]], columns=['Date', 'Value'])

In [95]: df = df.set_index('Date')

In [96]: df
Out[96]: 
                            Value
Date                             
2012-11-22 12:12:40.905739   12.1    

In [97]: df.index
Out[97]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2190-12-31 02:18:44.941732032]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [98]: df = df.reset_index()

In [99]: df
Out[99]: 
                           Date  Value
0 2190-12-31 02:18:44.941732032   12.1
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is with numpy? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1704

Answer (score 1):

Updating to a newer version of numpy (and rebuilding pandas) seems to have fixed the problem.

> > > numpy.**version**
> > >       '1.8.0.dev-fd78546'
> > >       pandas.**version**
> > >       '0.9.1.dev-85d982d'

I posted and closed the issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2329

Feel free to close this question on stackoverflow if you think it is superfluous, though who knows maybe someone else will run into it too.